# MySQL - Which one has better performance; 'nested selects' or 'order by'?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have to get the country with the highest amount of clients from a data base. I have the following code on MySQL using nested selects:

```
select name as Country, max(cnt) as 'Amount of clients'
from (select countries.name, count(clients.id) as cnt from clients
inner join countries on clients.country = countries.id) as Results;
```

The code is working fine. But I wonder if it could be better in terms of time performance if instead of that I use ORDER BY, like for example:

```
select countries.name as Country, count(clients.id) as 'Amount of clients'
from clients inner join countries on clients.country = countries.id
order by 'Amount of clients' desc limit 1;
```

Could someone explain me if there is an important difference between them and if one of both is better or if it doesn't really matters. Thanks.

Comment: Neither of these queries produce the correct result https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=94c163cf97a372ff7784d40b1eeba8c7 and will fail completely if only_full_group_by is set https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=94c163cf97a372ff7784d40b1eeba8c7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. If the query is used seldom and works quickly you shouldn't optimize it.

Having said that I personally would use the second option. Subqueries are harder to read, and should be avoided to make it easier for the next developer (that might very well be you). And they tend to get BAD performance issues if not done correctly.

Just note that "limit" is mysql specific, the query have to be rewritten if you want to run it on another sql server.

Answer (score 0):

As per Polygorial's Comment...

Your first query is wrong.

Your second query is wrong.  (Perhaps 3 errors.)

Revised 2nd query:

```
SELECT co.name AS Country,
       COUNT(*) AS 'Number of clients'
    FROM countries AS co
    LEFT JOIN clients AS cl  ON cl.country = co.id
    GROUP BY co.name
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

In *some* situations, this formulation may be faster:

```
SELECT  ( SELECT name FROM Country AS co
              WHERE cl.country = co.id
        ) AS Country,
        COUNT(*) AS 'Number of clients'
    FROM clients AS cl
    GROUP BY cl.country
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Perhaps even faster, in spite of being more complex.  Note how it pushes the `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` into the subquery:

```
SELECT  co.name
        cl.nc AS 'Number of clients'
    FROM (
        SELECT country,
               COUNT(*) AS nc
            FROM clients
            GROUP BY country
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
            LIMIT 1
         ) AS cl
    JOIN Country AS co  ON cl.country = co.id
```

For performance, we need to see the indexes you have.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.